# Rename mongo database

Tags: php, mongodb

I am doing project using mongodb and php. so here I tried to rename existing database using php. so I did following way to rename database.

- first I create new database( user new database name)
- read all records from old db and insert to new db
- then I drop old db

this is my code.

```
            $conn = new \MongoClient('mongodb://example.com:27017', array("connect" => TRUE));
            $exist_dbs = $conn->listDBs();

            foreach ($exist_dbs["databases"] as $databse) {
                if ($databse['name'] == $new_name) {
                    $new_name_is_exist = true;
                }
            }
            if (!$new_name_is_exist) {
                $db = new \MongoDB($conn, $old_name);

                //create new database
                $db_new = new \MongoDB($conn, $new_name);
                $collections = $db->getCollectionNames();

                foreach ($collections as $collection) {
                    //create collection
                    $new_collection = new \MongoCollection($db_new, $collection);

                    $mongo_collection = $db->$collection;
                    $objects = $mongo_collection->find();

                    while ($document = $objects->getNext()) {
                        //add records
                        $new_collection->insert($document);
                    }
                }
                $db->drop();
                $msg = 'database renamed';
            } else {
                $msg = 'given database name already exist';
            }
            $conn->close();
```

it works fine. but I would like to know is there any better way to rename mongo database using php?

Comment: Depends on whether the db has sharded collections or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy db (php + mongodb):

```
<?php

$rename = 'oldname';
$name = 'newname';
$mongo = (new MongoClient());
$db = $mongo->admin;
$response = $db->command(array(
    'copydb' => 1, 
    'fromhost' => 'localhost',
    'fromdb' => $rename,
    'todb' => $name
    ));

print_r($response);
```

Drop db (php + mongodb):

```
<?php

$name = 'oldname';
$mongo = (new MongoClient());
$db = $mongo->$name;
$response = $db->command(array(
    'dropDatabase' => 1
    ));

print_r($response);
```

Comment: `<?php print_r((new MongoClient())->'oldname'->drop());` — drop database lite :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$db=new new Mongo();
```

Copy old_db to new_db

```
$responseCopy = $db->admin->command(array(
    'copydb' => 1, 
    'fromhost' => 'localhost',
    'fromdb' => 'old_db',
    'todb' =>'new_db'
    ));
```

Now drop old_db

```
if($responseCopy['ok']==1){
 $responseDrop=$db->old_db->command(array('dropDatabase' => 1));
 //OR 
 $responseDrop =$db->old_db->drop();
}
```

Show Output

```
print_r($responseCopy);
print_r($responseDrop);
```

Output will be something like this

```
Array ( [ok] => 1 ) 
Array ( [dropped] => old_db [ok] => 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
$mongo = new MongoClient('_MONGODB_HOST_URL_');
$query = array("renameCollection" => "Database.OldName", "to" => "Database.NewName", "dropTarget" => "true");

$mongo->admin->command($query);
```